# Ocultar parte de una palabra con CSS o HTML

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría saber como se podría ocultar parte de una palabra con CSS especialmente. Por ejemplo la palabra "tirachinas"
Que la parte de "tira" sea visible y la parte de chinas no aparezca.

Gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar `overflow: hidden;` y `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, claro que dependerá del tamaño del contenedor del texto.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo porfa?, con la palabra de tiachinas como prueba.

Comment: Claro, aquí va:  https://jsfiddle.net/L7cufb95/

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ocultar partes de una palabra puedes utilizar una combinación de propiedades como `position`, `overflow`, y `background-color`. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo puedes lograrlo:

En tu CSS:

```
.hide-part {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  }

.hide-part::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 65%; /* Puedes ajustar este valor según cuánto quieras ocultar */
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* Cambia esto al color de fondo de tu contenedor o al color de fondo que desees */
  }
```

Y en tu HTML:

```
<p class="hide-part">tirachinas</p>
```

En este ejemplo, la clase `.hide-part` se aplica al elemento `<p>`, pero puedes aplicarla a cualquier otro elemento según tus necesidades. La pseudo-clase `::after` se utiliza para crear una capa blanca que cubre la parte derecha de la palabra, ocultando así una porción de la palabra, recuerda ajustar el valor en `width` según tus necesidades.